Optimize Mariadb query with 4+ million row
I'm working on a chatting app and running MariaDb. I'm trying to create a query to get all the recent conversations, i.e. last message and from which user, similar to iMessage/Messenger/WhatsApp does when you open it. The chatmessages table contains 4+M of rows. I tried using PARTITION BY OVER to get the desired results, but was getting very bad performance (1.5 seconds). I tried another approach to grouping but after spending a couple of days optimizing it, i ended up with a worst time  (1.7s).
What am I doing wrong, how can I optimize this. I'll share the 2 variations I created. Ideally im trying to get the query to execute in under 0.2sec . Main tables are the chatmessages holding the messages, sessions where each chatmessage refer to a session id, and visitors, representing the visitors. Each session is linked with a single visitor.
First Try - Using PARTITON OVER
There is a lot going on here, but the partition by alone take 1s to execute.
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetRecentConversations`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetRecentConversations`(
    `limit` INT,
    `offset` INT,
    `agent` CHAR(95),
    `property` VARCHAR(100),
    `closed` TINYINT
    )
BEGIN
    SET `limit` = IFNULL(`limit`, 30);
    SET `offset` = IFNULL(`offset`, 0);
    SET `agent` = IFNULL(`agent`, '');
    SET `property` = IFNULL(`property`, 0);
    SET `closed` = IFNULL(`closed`, 0);
    SELECT * 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT A.VisitorId, V.Name AS 'VisitorName', V.Picture AS 'ProfilePic', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CT.`TagsId`) AS 'TagsId' , 
            V.IsBlocked, A.MessageId, A.Message, A.CreatedAt AS 'MessageCreatedAt' , A.Attachment, A.ArticleId, A.SessionId, 
            V.PropertyId, P.Name AS 'PropertyName', AG.Agents, IF(AG.Agents IS NULL, 0,1) AS 'IsAttended',
            MAX( CASE WHEN A.FromAgentId IS NULL THEN A.CreatedAt END) AS 'LastSeen', A.rn
        FROM (
          SELECT S.Id AS 'SessionId', S.`VisitorId`, C.Message, C.Attachment, C.ArticleId, C.Id AS 'MessageId', C.CreatedAt, S.EndedOn, C.FromAgentId,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.`VisitorId` ORDER BY  C.`CreatedAt` DESC) AS rn
          FROM Sessions AS S
          LEFT JOIN ChatMessages C ON S.Id = C.SessionId
          WHERE S.IsDeleted = 0
        ) AS A
        LEFT JOIN Visitors V ON A.VisitorId = V.Id
        LEFT JOIN Properties P ON V.PropertyId = P.Id
        LEFT JOIN `contacttagvisitor` CT ON V.Id = CT.VisitorsId
        LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT SessionId, GROUP_CONCAT(AgentId) AS 'Agents'
                FROM sessionagents SA 
                LEFT JOIN aspnetusers U ON SA.AgentId = U.Id
                WHERE U.IsBot = 0
                GROUP BY SessionId
            ) AS AG ON A.SessionId =  AG.SessionId
        WHERE     ( (`agent`    = '') OR ( FIND_IN_SET( `agent`, AG.Agents ) > 0  )  ) AND 
              ( (`property` = 0 ) OR ( FIND_IN_SET( CAST(V.PropertyId AS CHAR),`property`) > 0)  ) AND 
              ( ( (`closed` = 0) AND (A.EndedOn IS NULL) ) OR 
                ( (`closed` = 1) AND (A.EndedOn IS NOT NULL) )
                )
        GROUP BY A.VisitorId
        HAVING (rn = 1) /* get only the last message in the session, done after grouping (HAVING) because we need the MAX LastSeen to work correctly */
        
    ) AS F
    ORDER BY MessageCreatedAt DESC LIMIT `limit` OFFSET `offset`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;


Second Try - Tried to avoid window functions

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetRecentConversationsOptimized`(
    `limit` INT,
    `offset` INT,
    `agent` CHAR(95),
    `property` VARCHAR(100),
    `closed` TINYINT
    )
BEGIN

    SET `limit` = IFNULL(`limit`, 30);
    SET `offset` = IFNULL(`offset`, 0);
    SET `agent` = IFNULL(`agent`, '');
    SET `property` = IFNULL(`property`, 0);
    SET `closed` = IFNULL(`closed`, 0);

    WITH agents AS (
        SELECT SessionId AS 'AgentsSessionId', GROUP_CONCAT(AgentId) AS 'Agents'
        FROM sessionagents SA 
        LEFT JOIN aspnetusers U ON SA.AgentId = U.Id
        WHERE U.IsBot = 0
        GROUP BY SessionId
    ),
    wtags AS (
        SELECT vs.Id AS 'VId', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CT.`TagsId`) AS 'TagsId' 
        FROM visitors vs
        INNER JOIN `contacttagvisitor` CT ON CT.VisitorsId = vs.Id
        GROUP BY vs.Id  
    ),
    ms AS (
        SELECT s.VisitorId, s.`Id` AS 'SessionId',  m.Message, m.`Attachment`, m.`ArticleId`, m.`Id` AS 'MessageId', m.`CreatedAt` AS 'MessageCreatedAt', s.`EndedOn`, m.`FromAgentId`,
            V.Name, V.Picture, V.IsBlocked, 
            P.Name AS 'PropertyName', P.Id AS 'PropertyId'
        FROM chatmessages m
        LEFT JOIN sessions S ON s.Id = m.SessionId
        LEFT JOIN visitors V ON S.VisitorId = V.Id
        LEFT JOIN properties P ON V.`PropertyId` = P.Id

        /*LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT SessionId, GROUP_CONCAT(AgentId) AS 'Agents'
                FROM sessionagents SA 
                LEFT JOIN aspnetusers U ON SA.AgentId = U.Id
                WHERE U.IsBot = 0
                GROUP BY SessionId
            ) AS AG ON S.Id =  AG.SessionId*/
        WHERE     /*( (@agent    = '') OR ( FIND_IN_SET( @agent, AG.Agents ) > 0  )  ) AND */
              ( (`property` = 0 ) OR ( FIND_IN_SET( CAST(V.PropertyId AS CHAR),`property`) > 0)  ) AND 
              ( ( (`closed` = 0) AND (S.EndedOn IS NULL) ) OR 
                ( (`closed` = 1) AND (S.EndedOn IS NOT NULL) )
                )   
        
    ) 
    
    SELECT ms.VisitorId, ms.Name AS 'VisitorName' , ms.Picture AS 'ProfilePic', wt.TagsId, 
        ms.IsBlocked, ms.MessageId, ms.Message, ms.MessageCreatedAt, ms.Attachment, ms.ArticleId, ms.SessionId, 
        ms.PropertyId, ms.PropertyName,  ag.Agents, IF(ag.Agents IS NULL, 0,1) AS 'IsAttended', LS.LastSeen
    FROM ms 
    LEFT JOIN wtags wt ON ms.VisitorId = wt.VId
    LEFT JOIN agents ag ON ms.SessionId = ag.AgentsSessionId
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT VisitorId AS 'VLSId', MAX( CASE WHEN ms.FromAgentId IS NULL THEN ms.MessageCreatedAt END) AS 'LastSeen'
        FROM ms
        GROUP BY VisitorId
    ) LS ON ms.VisitorId = LS.VLSId
    WHERE (VisitorId,MessageCreatedAt) IN 
        ( SELECT VisitorId, MAX(MessageCreatedAt)
          FROM ms
          GROUP BY VisitorId
        )
    ORDER BY MessageCreatedAt DESC LIMIT `limit` OFFSET `offset`;

    
END$$

DELIMITER ;

Relevant Table Definitions for reference

Chatmessages

CREATE TABLE `chatmessages` (
  `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `SessionId` char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
  `Message` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `FromAgentId` varchar(95) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdatedAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdatedBy` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `isRead` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Attachment` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ArticleId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isPrivate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `IX_ChatMessages_FromAgentId` (`FromAgentId`),
  KEY `IX_ChatMessages_SessionId` (`SessionId`),
  KEY `IX_ChatMessages_ArticleId` (`ArticleId`),
  KEY `IX_ChatMessages_CreatedAt` (`CreatedAt`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ChatMessages_AspNetUsers_FromAgentId` FOREIGN KEY (`FromAgentId`) REFERENCES `aspnetusers` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ChatMessages_KbArticles_ArticleId` FOREIGN KEY (`ArticleId`) REFERENCES `kbarticles` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ChatMessages_Sessions_SessionId` FOREIGN KEY (`SessionId`) REFERENCES `sessions` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci


Sessions

CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `VisitorId` char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
  `PropertyId` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `EndedOn` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdatedAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdatedBy` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `FacebookPageId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isOfflineHours` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `isHandedOver` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `IX_Sessions_PropertyId` (`PropertyId`),
  KEY `IX_Sessions_VisitorId` (`VisitorId`),
  KEY `IX_Sessions_FacebookPageId` (`FacebookPageId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Sessions_FacebookPages_FacebookPageId` FOREIGN KEY (`FacebookPageId`) REFERENCES `facebookpages` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Sessions_Properties_PropertyId` FOREIGN KEY (`PropertyId`) REFERENCES `properties` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Sessions_Visitors_VisitorId` FOREIGN KEY (`VisitorId`) REFERENCES `visitors` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci


Visitors

CREATE TABLE `visitors` (
  `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IP` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CountryCode` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Platform` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PropertyId` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `LastSeen` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `isDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdatedAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdatedBy` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `isBlocked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Picture` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ExternalId` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `IX_Visitors_PropertyId` (`PropertyId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Visitors_Properties_PropertyId` FOREIGN KEY (`PropertyId`) REFERENCES `properties` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci


Expected Output
VisitorId                             VisitorName   ProfilePic  IsBlocked  MessageId                             MessageCreatedAt            Attachment  ArticleId  SessionId                             PropertyId  IsAttended  LastSeen                    
83788605-2db3-49d5-bff7-472ad944ab21  extreme                   0          2318b732-88d0-47af-a388-3540743e49bd  2024-12-08 17:43:32.487863                         845df654-7268-484f-b6c0-63b4bcd827c0  1           1           2024-12-08 17:43:14.654195  
cbd82eba-9d5b-438f-a26b-0cfb37e24ca2  kai                       0          df9af340-26e6-4b8b-a009-199d43c631d6  2024-12-08 16:41:19.302200                         b5c0931d-f22e-4a62-bb93-d59f87d244c8  1           1           2024-12-08 16:41:19.302200  
5adcfa73-6223-444f-ab7e-80890b9e0367  moncoachdata              0          023a6de9-14be-4aeb-91c5-0ebc859a4da6  2024-12-08 15:15:54.533801                         554c322e-7b23-4238-95c2-41bd524b604f  1           1           2024-12-08 15:15:09.801974  
0100c4c3-74bb-4950-832f-1016471fdf8e                            0          458894d4-655d-46db-8bfb-b4734572e542  2024-12-08 14:48:37.568726                         b74496a2-ac0a-4bae-9923-bc049bfb3ad2  1           1           2024-12-08 13:28:12.729363  
c19cc8e5-b66f-423a-b3d0-39c9e3289980  support                   0          b6dc6a4b-e47b-45c2-87db-67152c803130  2024-12-08 12:33:59.969425              290        c66d114d-028a-4c9f-a66f-638c3b03d58d  1           1           2024-12-08 12:33:22.281014  
6baf0caa-d5dd-4620-ab3a-53fac178d2e7                            0          8f80518d-845f-4f82-a0e6-f5c39b8a9682  2024-12-08 08:59:44.332164                         6ba3ad53-e7dc-4272-a1c0-54f72e787ce8  1           1           2024-12-08 08:59:29.475363  
2b32a463-7498-4c7b-91d2-e4f5da55dbfc  sara                      0          895dc0da-b714-4e4f-bd24-945bd306b291  2024-12-08 08:46:07.301215                         e47a2432-cc94-4c8b-8b75-4c05b55ae114  1           1           2024-12-08 08:45:09.945227  
7dd08158-e88c-4596-8bf0-cbb04fe66131                            0          5aaaddad-85d6-41d0-b31f-fbeb6960c880  2024-12-08 08:01:25.456433                         f96abf69-cca1-4fc7-885f-079b8604d7ae  1           0           2024-12-08 08:01:25.456433  
c1ebbafe-a3fb-4f30-b431-7c956b917cb5                            0          5c75b60d-66cd-446b-9cbf-c4ee90aaaa46  2024-12-08 07:56:45.233012                         b776ecc1-f232-4f5d-9b9f-beaf029ceb58  1           0           2024-12-08 07:56:45.233012  
d975b3f5-beca-4368-b1cd-a816bcb0f9ba                            0          70044674-0da0-410d-8e04-97ab0568c63b  2024-12-08 07:06:23.526073                         cc468f1f-5be8-4f6f-8e0b-dcfbde1626a8  1           0           2024-12-08 07:06:23.526073  


Explain Results

The first PARTITION OVER QUERY explain results (the slowest part of the query)

id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys              key                        key_len  ref                        rows   Extra                         
1   SIMPLE       S      ALL                                                                                             17232  Using where; Using temporary  
1   SIMPLE       C      ref   IX_ChatMessages_SessionId  IX_ChatMessages_SessionId  144      db_prod_mirror.S.Id  2                                    


The second approach explain (whole query)

id  select_type      table        type    possible_keys                                        key                         key_len  ref                                 rows   Extra                                                                
1   PRIMARY          <subquery6>  ALL     distinct_key                                                                                                                  17232  Using temporary; Using filesort                                      
1   PRIMARY          m            ref     IX_ChatMessages_SessionId,IX_ChatMessages_CreatedAt  IX_ChatMessages_CreatedAt   8        <subquery6>.MAX(MessageCreatedAt)   1      Using index condition                                                
1   PRIMARY          S            eq_ref  PRIMARY,IX_Sessions_VisitorId                        PRIMARY                     144      db_prod_mirror.m.SessionId    1      Using where                                                          
1   PRIMARY          V            eq_ref  PRIMARY                                              PRIMARY                     144      <subquery6>.VisitorId               1      Using where                                                          
1   PRIMARY          P            eq_ref  PRIMARY                                              PRIMARY                     8        db_prod_mirror.V.PropertyId   1                                                                           
1   PRIMARY          <derived3>   ref     key0                                                 key0                        145      <subquery6>.VisitorId               10     Using where                                                          
1   PRIMARY          <derived2>   ref     key0                                                 key0                        145      db_prod_mirror.m.SessionId    2                                                                           
1   PRIMARY          <derived5>   ref     key0                                                 key0                        145      <subquery6>.VisitorId               2      Using where                                                          
6   MATERIALIZED     S            ALL     PRIMARY,IX_Sessions_VisitorId                                                                                                 17232  Using where; Using temporary                                         
6   MATERIALIZED     V            eq_ref  PRIMARY                                              PRIMARY                     144      db_prod_mirror.S.VisitorId    1      Using where                                                          
6   MATERIALIZED     m            ref     IX_ChatMessages_SessionId                            IX_ChatMessages_SessionId   144      db_prod_mirror.S.Id           2                                                                           
5   LATERAL DERIVED  S            ref     PRIMARY,IX_Sessions_VisitorId                        IX_Sessions_VisitorId       144      db_prod_mirror.S.VisitorId    1      Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort  
5   LATERAL DERIVED  V            eq_ref  PRIMARY                                              PRIMARY                     144      db_prod_mirror.S.VisitorId    1      Using where                                                          
5   LATERAL DERIVED  m            ref     IX_ChatMessages_SessionId                            IX_ChatMessages_SessionId   144      db_prod_mirror.S.Id           2                                                                           
3   DERIVED          CT           index   IX_ContactTagVisitor_VisitorsId                      PRIMARY                     148                                          467    Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort                         
3   DERIVED          vs           eq_ref  PRIMARY                                              PRIMARY                     144      db_prod_mirror.CT.VisitorsId  1      Using index                                                          
2   LATERAL DERIVED  SA           ref     IX_SessionAgents_AgentId,IX_SessionAgents_SessionId  IX_SessionAgents_SessionId  144      db_prod_mirror.S.Id           1      Using index condition                                                
2   LATERAL DERIVED  U            eq_ref  PRIMARY                                              PRIMARY                     382      db_prod_mirror.SA.AgentId     1      Using where                                                          



please include your table definitions, including index details. 2) please provide samole data and expected outputs 3) please provide the results of explain for all queries.


basically nobody can answer you a we don't know the tables and know othing of the wanted result also take one sample query and uye EXPLAIN sql-Query to see what the query actually does

@Shadow Just added all the requested info

@nbk I added the explain results

looks ok so far, but instead of 4 indexes use 1 combined and see what you get

the same for the sessions table also

@nbk sorry which 4 are you refering to?

all tables that have more than one KEY need a combined key with all columns simply all tables

Recommend ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON (query execution) and EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON (query planning) on as they give a richer result than the fixed format of EXPLAIN. As such it container more details and is better formatted.

it would be helpful to have an english description of precisely what you are trying to do and what the procedure parameters are for, rather than try to derive it from your query.

Reason
Didn't look at your queries thoroughly, but the problem is that there is no index. The first table that you have posted in Explain Results section, (column Type, first row, value ALL) reveals that, according to MariaDB documentation (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/#type-column):

ALL: A full table scan is done for the table (all rows are read). This is bad if the table is large and the table is joined against a previous table! This happens when the optimizer could not find any usable index to access rows.

Fix
I suppose that you want to search chat messages by their creation time (and, for example, get ten latest ones written by specified user). For this use case I would add a new index for chatmessages table:
create index chatmessages_by_creation_idx on chatmessages (CreatedAt);

There might be even more that one column in an index; maybe this will be better for your usecase:
-- Index by whole pair (CreatedAt, CreatedBy):
-- Good if these two are usually used in conjunction
create index chatmessages_by_creation_idx on chatmessages (CreatedAt, CreatedBy);

You may try to create both of these indexes, you may want to use different columns, maybe it will be better to include more columns. I recommend experimenting with indexes if it is not production database (or create a database copy with testing data on your own computer and experiment with indexes there).
Resources
More about indexes here (sorted from the simplest to most detailed):

https://www.codecademy.com/article/sql-indexes
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indexing-in-databases-set-1/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index
and many more

And about MariaDB's EXPLAIN:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain
About EXPLAIN SELECT: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/#columns-in-explain-select


Hello, Thanks. I have though indices on the CreatedAt, SessionId, VisitorId, and most of the columns im looking to find in the Partition by, what more can be done in terms of indexing?


UUIDs are inefficient.  See UUIDs

Composite index(es) are needed.  See below.

Take advantage of the clustering of the PRIMARY KEY rather than jumping around using a random (UUID) PK.

Avoid using "row constructors" such as `WHERE (a, b) IN (...).

Avoid using IN (SELECT ... )  Use a JOIN, LEFT JOIN, or EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )

To make it easier for me to read the queries, please qualify each column with the table (or table alias).

Avoid casting CAST(V.PropertyId AS CHAR).  If this is EAV, see Entity-Attribute-Value

Avoid OFFSET.  See Pagination

See if you can turn GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CT.TagsId) AS 'TagsId' (and its GROUP BY) into ( SELECT DISTINCT TagsId FROM contacttagvisitor WHERE ... ) AS TagsId

Don't say LEFT JOIN when it is really INNER JOIN:  LEFT JOIN  aspnetusers U  ON SA.AgentId = U.Id WHERE  U.IsBot = 0

Avoid using more than one "derived table" in a query.  This is because all but one will have to be materialized into a temp table and possibly an index be generated.  For example:
  ...
  FROM ms  -- this is effectively a derived table
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT A.VisitorId
      FROM (
    LEFT JOIN ChatMessages ...
  ) AS A   -- second derived table
  LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT ...
      ) AS AG ... -- third



Some of these INDEXes may help:
sessions:  INDEX(VisitorId, MessageCreatedAt)
Sessions:  INDEX(IsDeleted, Id,  VisitorId, EndedOn)
wtags:  INDEX(VId,  TagsId)
agents:  INDEX(AgentsSessionId,  Agents)
Visitors:  INDEX(PropertyId, Id,  Name, Picture, IsBlocked)
contacttagvisitor:  INDEX(VisitorsId,  TagsId)
ChatMessages:  INDEX(SessionId, CreatedAt)

After you have implemented some of these suggestions, come back for more suggestions.
